# Can I use the uint64_t in a for block?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

So I'm trying to write a code that it finds all the prime numbers before 10 000 000 000 000. So I use `uint64_t` for this in some variables. I also want to place the results in a plain text file, sounds easy. Or that's what I thought. I compile the code with

```
gcc -lm --std=c11 primenumbers.c -o primes
```

And I get 0 errors or warnings... good for me! But then when I execute the program I got the awful error message

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

At first I thought it could be that I was not assigning correctly the memory for the string, so I proceed to use `malloc()`/`free(0` everywhere when I need to make bigger the string, and nope, it still keep showing up.

So here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool test_number(uint64_t c);

int main(void){
    uint64_t b = 10000000000000;
    uint64_t i;
    char *s = " ";
    char *helper = "";
    char *helper_two;
    char *helper_three;
    int format = 0;

    FILE *ptrPrimes;


    for(i = 2; i <= b; i++){
        if (test_number(i)){
            format++;
            sprintf(helper_three, "%llu", i);
            helper = malloc(strlen(s));
            helper_two = malloc(sizeof(strlen(helper_three)) + 1);
            sprintf(helper_two, " %s", helper_three);
            strcpy(helper, s);
            free(s);
            if(format % 120 == 0){
                s = malloc(sizeof(helper) + sizeof(helper_two) + 1);
                sprintf(s, "%s%s\n", helper, helper_two);
            }else{
                s = malloc(sizeof(helper) + sizeof(helper_two));
                sprintf(s, "%s%s", helper, helper_two);
            }
            free(helper);
            free(helper_two);
            helper_three = NULL;
        }        
    }

    if((ptrPrimes = fopen("primenumbers.txt", "w")) != NULL){
        fprintf(ptrPrimes, "%s", s);
    }else{
        printf("Sorry mate, an error curred\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool test_number(uint64_t c){
    uint64_t i;
    c = sqrt(c);
    for(i = 2; i <= c; i++){
        if(c % i == 0) return false;        
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then I thought it may be the use of an `uint64_t` in a for header. So what do you think it may be the error?

**EDIT**

I tried all the suggestions and some more of my own and the code now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool test_number(uint64_t c);

int main(void){
    uint64_t b = 10000000000000;
    uint64_t i;
    char *s;
    char *helper;
    char *helper_two;
    char *helper_three;
    uint64_t format = 0;

    FILE *ptrPrimes;


    for(i = 2; i <= b; i++){
        if (test_number(i)){
            printf("%llu\n", i);
            format++;
            helper_three = malloc(sizeof(char) * snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", i));
            sprintf(helper_three, "%llu", i);
            helper = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s));
            helper_two = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(helper_three) + 1);
            sprintf(helper_two, " %s", helper_three);
            strcpy(helper, s);
            if(format % 120 == 0){
                s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(helper) + sizeof(char) * strlen(helper_two) + 1);
                sprintf(s, "%s%s\n", helper, helper_two);
            }else{
                s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(helper) + sizeof(char) * strlen(helper_two));
                sprintf(s, "%s%s", helper, helper_two);
            }
            free(helper);
            free(helper_two);
            free(helper_three);
        }        
    }

    if((ptrPrimes = fopen("primenumbers.txt", "w")) != NULL){
        fprintf(ptrPrimes, "%s", s);
    }else{
        printf("Sorry mate, an error curred\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool test_number(uint64_t c){
    uint64_t i;
    uint64_t b = sqrt(c);
    for(i = 2; i <= b; i++){
        if(!(i % 2) && i != 2) continue;
        if(c % i == 0) return false;        
    }
    return true;
}
```

And it's everything is OK after the number 29, for some reason (obviously) I got this error message:

> 2
>   3
>   5
>   7
>   11
>   13
>   17
>   19
>   23
>   29
>
> *** Error in `./primes': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000258f100 ***
>
> ======= Backtrace: =========                                                                                                                                             /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x77e35)[0x7f8f212abe35]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x8051a)[0x7f8f212b451a]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f8f212b7ccc]
>   ./primes[0x400a8f]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f8f21254580]
>   ./primes[0x4007b9]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 13507592                           /home/lain/primes 00601000-00602000
>   r--p 00001000 fd:02 13507592
>   /home/lain/primes 00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 fd:02 13507592
>   /home/lain/primes 0258f000-025b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [heap] 7f8f1c000000-7f8f1c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f8f1c021000-7f8f20000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f8f2101d000-7f8f21033000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 789942
>   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-201 7f8f21033000-7f8f21232000 ---p 00016000
>   fd:00 789942                     /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-201
>   7f8f21232000-7f8f21233000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 789942
>   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-201 7f8f21233000-7f8f21234000 rw-p 00016000
>   fd:00 789942                     /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.3.1-201
>   7f8f21234000-7f8f213eb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 788930
>   /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so 7f8f213eb000-7f8f215eb000 ---p 001b7000 fd:00
>   788930                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so
>   7f8f215eb000-7f8f215ef000 r--p 001b7000 fd:00 788930
>   /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so 7f8f215ef000-7f8f215f1000 rw-p 001bb000 fd:00
>   788930                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so
>   7f8f215f1000-7f8f215f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f8f215f5000-7f8f216f6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 788938
>   /usr/lib64/libm-2.22.so 7f8f216f6000-7f8f218f5000 ---p 00101000 fd:00
>   788938                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.22.so
>   7f8f218f5000-7f8f218f6000 r--p 00100000 fd:00 788938
>   /usr/lib64/libm-2.22.so 7f8f218f6000-7f8f218f7000 rw-p 00101000 fd:00
>   788938                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.22.so
>   7f8f218f7000-7f8f21918000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 788921
>   /usr/lib64/ld-2.22.so 7f8f21ad3000-7f8f21ad6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f8f21b14000-7f8f21b17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f8f21b17000-7f8f21b18000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 788921
>   /usr/lib64/ld-2.22.so 7f8f21b18000-7f8f21b19000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00
>   788921                     /usr/lib64/ld-2.22.so
>   7f8f21b19000-7f8f21b1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fffa035b000-7fffa037d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [stack] 7fffa0381000-7fffa0383000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vvar] 7fffa0383000-7fffa0385000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vsyscall]

And I don't quite get it why is everything OK until '29'.

Comment: `free(s);` - when this line is first executed, the string `s` points to static memory.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to find out where is the segfault

Comment: Or, better, just rewrite all the code using C++ strings.

Comment: @kfx why do you have to say that? It's [tag:c] not [tag:c++], can you tell me a way to use [tag:c++] strings for a [tag:c] program?

Comment: @iharbob: because there are so many bugs in the code related to memory allocation. Most/all would be prevented if C++ was used. The OP is not saying "I want to use C", he/she's saying "I want to solve find some prime numbers".

Comment: all of your mallocs are wrong. It would be far simpler to get rid of all the malloc and all the char pointers, and use an array and just do a single `snprintf` into that array, instead of all these bizarre partial strings

Comment: @kfx you could say that haskell or python should have been used instead... there's really no point trying to start a language war. The way this site works is that OP asked a question about how to code in C and so the answers should be about coding in C. Nobody cares that you'd personally use a different language.

Comment: @kfx, Using [tag:python] would help too but that's not the point. The question is tagged [tag:c] so it's apparently a requirement.

Comment: @Lain: you algorithm is also infeasible, just saying. There are `n/log(n)` prime numbers less than `n`. No way they will fit in a single string.

Comment: 346,065,536,839 prime numbers are less than your boundary: that's far more than RAM of a normal computer can hold.

Comment: @kfx you're right, I forgot the pi function. This lame and sad.

Comment: `strcpy(helper, s);` helper might be too small.

Comment: @kfx Asking OP to use a different programming language is not a productive comment.

Comment: Do not change you post to `[Solved]`.  Post reverted.  You can select an answer.  Even post and select your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've came with this answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool test_number(uint64_t c);

int main(void){
    uint64_t b = 9223372036854775783;
    uint64_t i;
    char *s;
    char *helper;
    char *helper_two;
    char *helper_three;
    uint64_t format = 0;

    FILE *ptrPrimes;


    for(i = 2; i <= b; i++){
        if (test_number(i) == true){
            //printf("%llu", i);
            format++;
            helper_three = malloc(sizeof(char) * snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", i));
            sprintf(helper_three, "%llu ", i);
            helper_two = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(helper_three) + 1));
            strcpy(helper_two, helper_three);
            if (format == 1){
                s = malloc(sizeof(char));
                sprintf(s, "%s", helper_three);
               }else{
                if (s != NULL){
                    helper = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) +1));
                    strcpy(helper, s);
                    free(s);
                    if(format % 120 == 0){
                        s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(helper) + sizeof(char) * (strlen(helper_two) + 1) +1);
                        strcpy(s, helper);
                        strcat(s, helper_two);
                        strcat(s, "\n");
                    }else{
                        s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(helper) + sizeof(char) * (strlen(helper_two) + 1));
                        strcpy(s, helper);
                        strcat(s, helper_two);
                    }
                }
            }
            free(helper);
            free(helper_two);
            free(helper_three);
        }        
    }

    if((ptrPrimes = fopen("primenumbers.txt", "w")) != NULL){
        fprintf(ptrPrimes, "%s", s);
    }else{
        printf("Sorry mate, an error ocurred\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool test_number(uint64_t c){
    uint64_t i;
    uint64_t b = sqrt(c);

    switch(c){
        case 1:
            return false;
        case 2:
            return true;
    }

    if(c % 2 == 0) return false;

    for(i = 3; i <= b; i += 2){
        if(c % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I was just trying to re-learn some concepts of C(11), so it wasn't necessary that the code were optimized, it was never the intention (even i I tweaked the test_number function). But anyway thank you all for the help.

I always needed to use `sizeof` and `strlen`, `sizeof` to get the size of the char on my system and strlen for the length of the string (obviously) so I could get the right amount of memory to save the string. I shouldn't not only use `strlen` alone. I'd getting memory for an unknown struct (with size of the string's length, wich doesn't make sense anyway).

One of my bigger mistakes, was that I wasn't considering the '\0' character in the string. It appears that `strlen` ignores it (*cringes*). And again: thanks for your help.

P.S. If you use `clang` you'll get a warning because of the "%llu" format specifier. I found it interesting, I though `clang` would be bigger in its support for some features than `gcc`. Not wanting to start a war between compilers, both are great tools, just that: ***tools***.

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
  sprintf(helper_three, "%llu", i);
```

`helper_three` is not allocated any memory. So, the memory location pointed by `helper_three` is not essentially *valid*. Any attempt to access invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side-effects.

You need to allocate memory to `helper_three` before *writing* into it.

After that,

```
 helper_two = malloc(sizeof(strlen(helper_three)) + 1);
```

is pretty wrong. What you need is

```
helper_two = malloc(strlen(helper_three) + 1);
```

Then, the `sizeof(helper)` and other `sizeof(pointer)` does not work the way you expected. Using `sizeof` on a pointer evaluates to the size of the pointer itself, not to the amount of memory allocated to the pointer. In case, those pointers hold a *string*, you need to use `strlen()` to get the size.

Comment: That's awrong too, what I need is: `helper_two = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(helper_three) + 1))`

Answer (score 2):

This is very disturbing

```
sizeof(strlen(...));
```

you don't need the `sizeof` there.

But almost all your `malloc()`s allocate space the wrong way. If you want to predict the length of the `sprintf()` try `snprintf()` with `0` length a `NULL` target buffer, check the return value.

Comment: *selfautofacepalm* I was trying some solutions, and I completely forgot to change some things.